# Copy-Item copies directory as well as contents to UNC path

Tags: powershell, unc, powershell-1.0

I'm trying to take the contents of a folder and copy it to another using PowerShell 1.0. Pretty simple stuff and it all works fine using `Copy-Item $from $to -recurse` if I am copying from a local folder to a local folder. However, if the `$to` variable is a UNC path, it seems to copy the `$from` directory, not just its contents.

e.g.

```
$from = "c:\temp\rhysc\" 
$to = "\\OtherMachineName\ShareFolder\"  
Copy-Item $from $to -recurse
```

...ends up up creating a folder `\\OtherMachineName\ShareFolder\rhysc` instead of just copying over the contents of the folder.

I want to maintain the structure of the `$from` directory that I am copying over so my basic attempt at piping didn't work (everything got dumped in the root of the `$to` folder)

```
Get-ChildItem $from -recurse | Copy-Item -destination $to
```

Comment: Are you sure the local copy didn't also copy the directory?  That's the behavior I see unless you do what David suggests.

Comment: yep, 100% sure, my tests were relying on it. It only broke changed behaviour when i changed the path to UNC.

Comment: See also [How can I copy a directory, overwriting its contents if it exists using Powershell?](http://superuser.com/q/544520)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try:

`$from = "c:\temp\rhysc\*"`

Comment: powershell 3 I had to omit the asterisk and use -recurse.

Comment: Doesn't seem to copy sub-folders correctly (with or without the -recurse).

Comment: @user1009974 This was with Powershell 1.0, not sure if this has changed?