# Powershell Copy-Item copies contents of UNC subdirectory which cannot copy onto leaf

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Apologies in advance for likely confusion arising from my redefinition of the following terms for this question;

- directory (the top level directory)
- subdirectory (a directory below the top level directory)
- sub_subdirectory (a subdirectory of the subdirectory)
- contents of directory (files and subdirectories)
- contents of subdirectory (files and sub_subdirectories)

---

### Question

I'm trying to use Windows 7 Powershell 3.0  `Copy-Item` function to copy the six subdirectories of one directory, into another directory; fairly simple stuff. Note, these directories reside on a network, the UNC paths of which have been mapped to drives in windows environment as in; 
`H:\ = \\servername\path`

In the following example, the top level directory is itself copied, rather than just its contents (which happen to be six subdirectories and their contents)

```
$from = "H:\temp\toplvl_dir - backup"

$to = "H:\temp\newdir"

Copy-Item $from -Destination $to -Recurse

# Creates:
# H:\temp\newdir\toplvl_dir - backup
```

This is undesirable.
Progress was made in borrowing the format of the David-Tchepak [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905553/copy-item-copies-directory-as-well-as-contents-to-unc-path) using " * " postfix `$from = "H:\temp\toplvl_dir\* "` which partly worked in that it did copy only contents...

```
$from = "H:\temp\toplvl_dir - backup\*"

$to = "H:\temp\newdir"

Copy-Item $from -Destination $to -Recurse

# Creates:
# H:\temp\newdir\{copied contents of .\toplvl_dir - backup\NN_subdir\}
```

...but unfortunately those contents originated from one level *below* the desired level: i.e. the contents of the *subdirectory* `.\toplvl_dir - backup\NN_subdir\`, rather than the contents of the **directory** .\toplvl_dir... 
The `$from` directory in the example above in fact contains six subdirectories `"\01_subdir", "\02_subdir"...."\06_subdir"`, each of which contains an identical 'tree' consisting a lone subdirectory which itself contains lots of files. The full path looks like this;

```
e.g. H:\temp\toplvl_dir - backup\NN_subdir\lone_subdirectory\{lots of files}
```

`Copy-Item` seemingly tries to copy **the sub_subdirectory** i.e. `lone_subdirectory`, reporting an error for each `NN_subdir`; **"container cannot be copied onto existing leaf item"**. I understand in so far that each copy iteration of the contents of `NN_subdir` beyond the first `01_subdir`, is a repetition of `lone_subdirectory` which will give rise to a directory name conflict, but I do not understand why with the syntax applied, `Copy-Item` is trying to copy the *sub_subdirectories* rather than the *subdirectory* `.\toplvl_dir - backup\NN_subdir\`

How to make a simple call to `Copy-Item` to copy the *contents of the top level directory* `.\toplvl_dir - backup\*` into `.\newdir` i.e. the six subdirectories themselves *and* their contents!?

Please feel free to say if I am being unreasonable in expecting to be able to complete this operation in a single line call to `Copy-Item`?

```
# Desired Result using a one-line call to Copy-Item:
H:\temp\newdir\01_subdir\lone_subdirectory\{lots of files}
H:\temp\newdir\02_subdir\lone_subdirectory\{lots of files}
H:\temp\newdir\03_subdir\lone_subdirectory\{lots of files}
H:\temp\newdir\04_subdir\lone_subdirectory\{lots of files}
H:\temp\newdir\05_subdir\lone_subdirectory\{lots of files}
H:\temp\newdir\06_subdir\lone_subdirectory\{lots of files}
```

:-S

Comment: can you run the same command without the wildcard? `$from = "H:\temp\toplvl_dir - backup\"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify, If I have a folder structure like this:

```
C:\src\01\lone\a.txt
C:\src\02\lone\b.txt
C:\dest
```

You are looking for a 1-line Copy-Item command to produce a directory structure that looks like this?

```
C:\dest\01\lone\a.txt
C:\dest\02\lone\b.txt
```

Is that correct? If so, this command worked for me (albeit Win7, PS version 5):

```
Copy-Item -Path 'C:\src\*' -Destination 'C:\dest' -Recurse
```

Comment: Yes, thanks you have interpreted what I'm trying to do perfectly.

Comment: So I created a mirror of your structure on my local `C:\ `  The next part is confusing; I created a ps1 script with syntax as suggested, in `H:\ ` which is a network drive (mandatory practice), and a preliminary `del .\dest` cmd to erase prior attempts. Running the script from `H:\do_copy.ps1`, generated the familiar leaf error. **Then**, running a ps1 script locally, `C:\do_copy.ps1` *was* successful; *once*! But after re-running `H:\do_copy.ps1`, unsuccessfully, *subsequent running of the local script `C:\do_copy.ps1` is **also** unsuccessful...*

Comment: `#do_copy.ps1 
if (Test-Path 'C:\dest')
{
       Remove-Item 'C:\dest' - Recurse
}
Copy-Item -Path 'C:\src\*' -Destination 'C:\dest' -Recurse `

Comment: It looks like you are deleting your destination directory and its contents. Maybe try to modify your script with this added in: #do_copy.ps1 if (Test-Path 'C:\dest') { Remove-Item 'C:\dest' - Recurse } New-Item 'C:\dest' Copy-Item -Path 'C:\src\\*' -Destination 'C:\dest' -Recurse

Comment: Thank you Caleb! I feel stupid, and I love you. This worked for me; `New-Item 'C:\dest' -ItemType 'directory'`